# Remove folders Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

When I try to remove a folder called TerrariaServer in Ubuntu 14.04 with rm TerrariaServer, but it doesn't work, saying that rm: cannot remove ‘TerrariaServer’: Is a directory.

Sorry, new with ubuntu.

Comment: rm -rf TerrariaServer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are new with Linux, and you're probably using it just for setting up a game server.

`rm` is a command used for removing files, however, if you use it as `rm -rf` it will erase a folder without complaining about it. And if, for some reason you don't have permission to destroy the folder, use `sudo rm -rf`, as the `sudo` command grants you admin privileges.

After setting up your game server, it will probably not run at your first try. You should port forward your roter and make the firewall acept it.

Comment: I really needed to put the sudo command. But what is port forwarding?

Comment: Port forwarding is a process in which you redirect the connections to your roter on some port to your computer's port. See more at: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is because it is a directory, as the error message states.

`rm` is for removing *files*. Either use the `rmdir` command, or specify the additional `r` flag for recursion, so `rm -r TerrariaServer`...

In general: it always is a good idea to take a look at a commands "man page" when in doubt about its usage: `man rm`